# Why tensorboard does not show the graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

This is a simple code which creates a single node in the computational graph using tensorflow:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.constant(5)
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./path', tf.Session().graph)
writer.close()
```

When I try to visualize this graph using tensorboard, no graph is shown. This is my terminal code:

```
tensorboard --logdir=[![enter image description here][1]][1]path --port 6006
```

What is wrong with my codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no computational graph in your code. There is just alone vertex that does nothing. Create a graph with at least one op:

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant(5)
b = tf.constant(5)
c = a + b

with tf.Session() as sess:
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('path', sess.graph)
    writer.close()
```

and you will see it

Comment: In the second lecture of the Stanford CS20SI course, the lecturer says that `tf.constant` is an operation. So, it seems that a graph with only a constant can be treated as a computational graph? Am I right?

Comment: @Hossein it can be treated (graph with one vertex is a graph), but you don't know how TB was implemented. Try to put a variable instead of a constant.